# How to prevent c++builder error dialog box?

Tags: c++builder

Using C++Builder v10.4.2.

When compiling, errors pop-up a modal dialog which I have to close to go to the offending line(s).

Is there a way to turn this off and have the IDE take you directly to the error?

I believe the IDE used to work like this on previous versions.

Comment: Which error dialog are you referring to? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Compile errors do not use dialog boxes (at least I never saw any) so its most likely runtime error (once you run your application) and those are not produced by IDE nor App itself but by OS error handling. The usual is division by zero or invalid floating point operation or overflow which if in repeated call or timer can be nasty to break from. In case you running from IDE turn on error checking (code guard) if you have any in your version. That will break point at the wrong line ... and reveal tons of hidden errors

Comment: The dialog title is "Build Unit", with a "! Failed, There are errors."  message. Not sure how to include a screenshot here in stackoverflow.

Comment: @KevinM You will be able to post images directly once you hit reputation that allows it, for now post it anywhere (preferably imgur as that is what SO/SE uses too) and post link in here we will convert it to image for you (if you notify us by using `@nick` in you comment only one nick per comment and only nicks that are present in thread are working). Also in case its some kind of weird foreign related messgae box its possible to determine to which process it belongs for example like [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11920/4709) there surely are utility tools for this

Comment: image is here: https://imgur.com/15ckcZp

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. If you don't have background compilation turned on, you get this modal dialog which you must close to proceed.
If background compilation is turned on, you get a similar dialog though non-modal, which allows you to go to the offending line without closing the box.
Why there would be two versions is a mystery.